# Reoccurring Hash Problem Using `apt` on Jammy

Tags: apt, 22.04, hash

```
# apt update 
...
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.xz  
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:3842515 [weak]
    - SHA256:0faa1d52c63b422f9413ceb4e501e0faee7cc307c02a07a0e72e373537cbc9b2
    - SHA1:524075b6694a5a0b40cddd77e34d387910594a2b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:908ad587d123e8ff833cf6e30eeaf382 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:605fb7c7aef876dd40b0195aa9c26df7d9396620c0ad0d69c9b01cb0b8d927b7
    - SHA1:524075b6694a5a0b40cddd77e34d387910594a2b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:908ad587d123e8ff833cf6e30eeaf382 [weak]
    - Filesize:3842515 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 15:27:28 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 17:51:23 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

a "--fix-missing" on apt-get does not make this problem go away, either.  is this a known problem and/or is there a known solution to start over the hashes?

Answer (score 1):

the solution was waiting 2 days.  apparently, someone fixed this upstream.

Comment: This issue is due to the website archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.xz being down. If it hadn't come back up, the only solution would be to find another link to that package and change the configuration to use that instead.